# spark standalone running on docker cleanup not running

Tags: apache-spark, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm running spark on standalone mode as a docker service where I have one master node and one spark worker. I followed the spark documentation instructions:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

to add the properties where the spark cluster cleans itself and I set those in my docker_entrypoint

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=900 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=900
```

and verify that it was enables following the logs of the worker node service

My question is do we expect to get all directories located on `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` directory to be cleaned ? or does it only clean the application files
Because I still see some empty directories holding there

Comment: MsCurious, can you please provide the link for the documentation you referred?

Comment: just added them in the question